# Button Disable Xcode 5.1.1

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

[image]

I am getting a very weird issue while disabling a button in Xcode 5.1.1 and iOS SDK 7.1.

My button gets hidden when I disable the button in `- (void)viewDidLoad` or `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` or in the `nib`.

The same code is properly working for iOS 7.0 and below.

```
myButton.enabled = NO;
```

Is this an Apple bug?
I had tried in different projects also but result is same.

Comment: Can you tell where your button is not getting disabled ?

Comment: actually it's getting disabled and hidden both

Comment: who has given the negative rating... and why so.. if you can't resolve someone problem then don't give negative rating..

Comment: I just disable the button in a sample project and it just  got disabled (greyed out) but it din't get hidden. I'm using XCODE 5.1.1 and ios 7.1. So could you check whether u have set the hidden property of button to YES.

Comment: Can you provide the code and a screenshot of the Interface Builder?

Comment: I am setting the image using sprite sheet.. is this affecting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem exists while i am setting the image. I am setting the image of each button using SpriteSheet. The image gets added dynamically after slicing and resizing in background. So whatever the state of button is it just set's the image of Disabled and normal state.

Now to resolve this i checked whatever the state of button it just sets its

```
if (myButton.state == UIControlStateDisabled)
{
   myButton.enabled = YES;
   [myButton setImage:returnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal]; // return Image is the image which i get from sprite sheet after slicing and resizing.
   myButton.enabled = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using it Xcode 5.1 and it works perfectly on iOS 6 to iOS 7.1.

possibility is:
check whether the button is system or custom. it should be custom always.

Try making the button as myButton.enabled = YES; and see whether the button hidden in iOS 7.1.
Then check whether in nib file, you have set clear color for disabled state of the button.

Answer (score 0):

May be your button is placed below another ui object (i.e. UIView), so it is hidden and disabled. If another view's user interaction is enabled, and this view happens to be above the button, then touch event is taken over by that view. Another issue can be that your button is beyond super view's bounds and this super view has clipToSubview enabled.

Comment: nothing is like this.. my button is top of all the views in view hierarchy and it's in the middle.. and on my another button click i am just enabling my last button so it's showing my last button and i can easily click on that after that....